# Regex to not include letters and values without spaces after commas

Tags: regex, google-forms

I have a text box and I need to validate the date that is being input. I’d like the users to only input numbers and if they input multiple numbers separated by a comma I need them to always add a space after the comma. I want to only accept data that looks like this: 1234, 15482, 086392 or 16843
I don’t want to accept data if it looks anything like this: 13738,74848, abc , 6a738

I’m using a google form here so I need a Regex that matches the above criteria.

I have two Regex ,[^ ] and [A-Za-z] but I can’t figure out how to connect them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write the pattern as:

```
^\d+(?:, \d+)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:, \d+)*` Optionally repeat matching a comma and a space followed by 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UpPKwU/1)